# Recovery (restore) over PXE

Tags: backup, data-recovery, restore, pxe, recovery

How to do I restore my backup file *(AOMEI or EaseUS)* to **multiple** computers over the Internet?

How can I take a backup of my computer *(Windows 10 Pro)* after **sysprep** on the computer and **restore** it to more than one computer over **LAN**?

`I will use switch for this.`

Comment: What are you planning to do with the licences?

Comment: I have licenses for the programs.

Comment: I was referring to Windows - you cannot use the licence on multiple machines (normally)

Comment: I will license all of them separately. I will do this in the company domain.